# How to get default value of field defined in data class using reflection?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, utility

I have data class with the format-

```
data class ABC(
    var first: String,
    var second: String,
    var third: String = "value"
)
```

I am using the below method to create an instance

```
T::class.java.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```

Now, this method calls the empty constructor and creates an instance with values of first as `null`, second as `null` and third as `null` , even though these are non-nullable field.

What I want is to create a instance with values of first as `null`, second as `null` but third as `value`.

Is there any way I can get the default value after creating the instance and than I will set the values manually?

I tried to directly get the memeber properties of the class but to call the property and get the value I have to pass the instance. If I pass the instance created with the above method I will get the value of third as null.

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example? https://pl.kotl.in/cJ4XqwPf2 shows that there is no such no-arg constructor.

Comment: The link you gave should be working. I don't why its not showing empty constructor. Even when its running in my spring boot application

Comment: That's because the Spring Framework includes a compiler plugin that adds no-arg constructors to every class, even when you don't declare one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an instance of `ABC` with properties `null`, `null` and default `"value"`, you first need to declare the constructor to allow nullable properties:

```
data class ABC(
    var first: String?,
    var second: String?,
    var third: String = "value"
)
```

I would strongly recommend that you consider making the data class immutable, by using `val` instead of `var`, unless you really need it to be mutable.

You're trying to use `T::class.java`, which is not going to work because Java does not have a concept of default parameters. You need to use `T::class` instead, which returns a `KClass`, part of Kotlin's reflection system which *does* understand default parameters.

To use default parameters, create a map of required parameters to values, leaving out those that you want to leave as default:

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.primaryConstructor

fun main() {
    val constructor = ABC::class.primaryConstructor ?: error("missing constructor")
    val params = constructor.parameters
    val instance = constructor.callBy(mapOf(params[0] to "p1", params[1] to "p2"))
    println(instance)  // ABC(first = p1, second = p2, third = value)
}
```

Comment: Problem I am trying to solve is to make a Generic function which initiates an instance of any data class without taking any parameters. This function should set the values of fields inside the data class either as null or as the default value assined to the field. After creating the instance, I will use reflection to get the specific field and will set the value of that field. 

The solution that you gave is strictly for ABC data class. Is there any way that we can make a generic function?

Comment: It would be very difficult to make this generic. Spring creates a no-arg secondary constructor which sets the properties to null, even if they are declared non-nullable. It can do this because it generates the constructor in bytecode, bypassing Kotlin syntax checking. However, this secondary constructor knows nothing about default parameters. If you want to use the default parameters, you have to use the primary constructor, but then you will have to know the names of all non-optional constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this using `callBy`, but I don't know any way that you can pass `null` to non-null properties, here is the code:

```
fun main() {
    val cons = ABC::class.constructors.first()
    val params = cons.parameters
    val x = ABC::class.constructors.first().callBy(
        mapOf(
            params[0] to "",
            params[1] to ""
        )
    )
    println(x)
}
```

Comment: Problem I am trying to solve is to make a Generic function which initiates an instance of any data class without taking any parameters. This function should set the values of fields inside the data class either as null or as the default value assined to the field. After creating the instance, I will use reflection to get the specific field and will set the value of that field. The solution that you gave is strictly for ABC data class. Is there any way that we can make a generic function?